# python numpy assigning by boolean indexing error "TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

In the last line of the following code I get an "TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type". Can you help?

Let me explain the code a bit. `randin()` function helps me get an array with elements in the range specified by `lb` and `ub`. In other words, you give `randin()` function two one dimensional numpy arrays `lb` and `ub`, and it returns array `r`, where this inequality holds for all elements `i`: `lb[i] <= r[i] < ub[i]`

In the one dimensional array`pos` some elements may be out of the range specified by `lb` and `ub`. I want only those elements to be randomly reproduced. And I want to use my already existing function `randin()` if possible. And of course I want to use fancy boolean indexing, not loops.

Thx.

```
import numpy as np
def randin(lb, ub):
    """return random array with elements between the
    elements of lb and ub. ub is not included."""
    r = ((ub - lb) * np.random.random(np.shape(lb))
        + lb)
    return r

## inputs
pos = np.array([1, -3, 5, -7, 9, -11])
ub = np.ones_like(pos) * 5
lb = np.zeros_like(pos)

## reproduce and assign out of range elements
high = pos > ub
low = pos < lb
hl = high | low
pos[hl] = randin(lb[hl], ub[hl])
```

Comment: on my win7, py2, your code outputs pos as `array([1, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1])` without exception

Comment: Works on linux, py2.7.5 too

Comment: Hmph. I am on win7, I have py 2.7.3 installed through pythonxy distribution. And I am certainly getting this error. To be more precise: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Answer (score 0):

When I initialize `pos` like `pos = np.array([1, -3, 5, -7, 9, -11], dtype = float)` the code runs without problem. So numpy was scared of assigning floats to integer elements. Not a bad idea.